# How to get my Current location with area, region, city, country

Tags: php

I want to get my Current (**area, area code or zip code, state, country**) location through
IP Address.

I am getting IP Address below code.

```
$myip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

output :- 122.161.20.5
```

My Code:-

```
<?php
$ip_addr = '122.161.20.5';
$geoplugin = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_addr) );

if ( is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude']) && is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude']) ) {

$lat = $geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude'];
$long = $geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($geoplugin);
echo '<pre>';
?>
```

Above the IP ADDRESS provide the location **New Delhi** but this is not my current location.

Please help me.

Comment: That might be the best that this particular service can do. Try a different one, or offer your users a way to correct their auto-detected location.

Answer (score 2):

GeoLocation isn't really foolproof. Most of the time, you'll end up getting the Lat / Long of your ISP.

Comment: I was 8 seconds faster :P

Answer (score 1):

Thats not your fault. It looks like the IP-information in the databsase is not correct: http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/122.161.20.5

Such databases (like GeoIP) often have wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

Maxmind Geo API is given a free trial verison to locate the IP,you can try that it is easy to implement and also has a light version.

http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing

Please check this link.

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/ YOu cansee here how to implement this.

It is easy to implement and if not cater your need you can purchase the total databse.